title fontsize issue it should be in single line
I have a match card in which I want the match title. If it doesn't fit in a single line, the font size should automatically decrease.-->
 <div className={`matchCard ${classStyle}`} onClick={()=> handleNavigate&& handleNavigate(matchCardData?.flightList[0]?._id)}>
    <div className="subContainer">
    <div className="leftSubContainer">
      <span className="text-label">{matchCardData.tripStartArea || matchCardData?.flightList?.[0]?.departingAirport}</span>
      <span className="icon icon-aeroplane"></span>
       <span className="text-label">{matchCardData.tripEndArea || matchCardData?.flightList?.[0]?.destinationAirport}</span></div>
    <p className="rightSubContainer">{ formatDate(matchCardData?.fixtureDate)?.toUpperCase() || matchCardData.date}</p>
    </div>
    <div className="matchBody">
      <div className="subMatchBody">
      <h1 className="matchTitle" style={{ fontSize: (matchCardData?.team1?.split(" ").some(word => word.length > 8)) || (matchCardData?.homeTeam?.split(" ").some(word => word.length > 8)) ? "18px" : "" }}>{matchCardData.team1?.replace(/_/g, ' ') || matchCardData?.homeTeam?.toUpperCase()?.replace(/_/g, ' ')}</h1>
      <h2 className="matchSubTitle">{t("VS")}.&nbsp;&nbsp;{matchCardData.team2?.replace(/_/g, ' ') ||matchCardData?.otherTeam?.toUpperCase()?.replace(/_/g, ' ')}</h2>   
      </div>
      <div className="matchRightContainer">
       {(matchCardData.amount || matchCardData?.ticketPrice) && <span>£</span>}
        <div>{matchCardData.amount || matchCardData?.ticketPrice || "TBC"}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

i tried with length but it is not what my head want
